# Unity encountered problems accessing the Huawei SDK, import agconnect-services.json can not be read

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In Unity packaging, let the import agconnect-services.json in the document to read, import the file into the Unity project can not be read.The URL in the configuration table (agconnect-services.json) can not be read,either.

[image: problem]

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "Unity packaging"? Are you using some plugin or doing this by hand?

Comment: pls click on the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carl，Unity access is  special.If you have used UDP, you can directly use UDP to access IAP.You can refer to the doc https://distribute.dashboard.unity.com/guideDoc/HUAWEI
Connect the UDP IAP with Huawei, so that your application is 4.0 SDK and save the import json file.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the UDP plugin of unity to integrate HMS, you can refer to the official doc of the Unity:https://distribute.dashboard.unity.com/guideDoc/HUAWEI